# How can I import a text file into javascript from an external website using jquery $get()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

When the **button** in the following script gets clicked, it should **load** in the contents of the file "**http://tanguay.info/knowsite/data.txt**" and display it on the screen.

**What is the correct syntaxt so that the .get() function retrieves the data from the external website and puts it in #content?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
            google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
                $('#loadButton').click(loadDataFromExernalWebsite);
            });
            function loadDataFromExernalWebsite() {
                $('#content').html('new content');
                //$.get("http://tanguay.info/knowsite/data.txt", function(data) { alert(data); }, );
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <p>Click the button to load content:</p>
    <p id="content"></p>
    <input id="loadButton" type="button" value="load content"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727183/can-jquery-ajax-call-external-webservice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought of using [jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

I put together [a little code for a twitter app that loads](http://www.geekzone.co.nz/hellonearthisman/7218) a 2nd file with jquery load.

Comment: thanks, that looks like what I need, so I set up an example using .load() but it doesn't read in the file like it should, posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734676/why-doesnt-jquery-load-load-a-text-file-from-an-external-website