# Why doesn't jquery .load() load a text file from an external website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

In the example below, when I click the button, it says "Load was performed" but **no text is shown**.

I have a **clientaccesspolicy.xml** in the root directory and am able to asynchronously load the same file from **silverlight**. So I would think I should be able to access from **AJAX** as well.

**What do I have to change so that the text of the file http://www.tanguay.info/knowsite/data.txt is properly displayed in the #content element?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
            google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
                $('#loadButton').click(loadDataFromExernalWebsite);
            });
            function loadDataFromExernalWebsite() {
                $('#content').load('http://www.tanguay.info/knowsite/data.txt', function() {
                    alert('Load was performed.');
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <p>Click the button to load content:</p>
    <p id="content"></p>
    <input id="loadButton" type="button" value="load content"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Clientaccesspolicy has no affect on javascript. Most (maybe all?) modern browsers will prevent you from running cross-site-scripting, as it is a security risk.

Your alternative is to proxy that site through a file on your own site, like `/proxy.php?loadurl=http://theothersite.com` and then call that file via the Javascript, which would be allowed since it is from your domain.

Comment: I tried it with this http://www.tanguay.info/web/getdata/index.php?url=http://www.tanguay.info/knowsite/data.txt which internally gets text via PHP/CURL and works in silverlight for any site without clientaccesspolicy.xml, so it should work here. How do I debug this? In Firebug I see that .load() is being executed but not what it is returning, what error, etc. :-(

Comment: Using a proxy script like that will work in anything, but why not just add a `console.log` statement to see what is being echoed? And firebug **will** tell you all the HTTP requests and their responses. As long as you have the console open.

Comment: thanks for the console.log tip, but where in firebug do I get the http request/response/error information, posted a specific question on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734887/how-to-get-firebug-to-tell-me-what-error-jquerys-load-is-returning

Comment: I like this solution, how it calls another php program within the domain of the original script to load in the page you want, without getting javascripts cross site errors.
For Javescript to access a file in tanguay.info/web/getdata/ it must be called from within domain tanguay.info/ or it will generate a xss error.

Oh and jquery is up to version 1.4.2,  it might have some bug fixes?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any browser obeys `clientaccesspolicy.xml` or `crossdomain.xml` for XMLHttpRequest.

There are other mechanisms you can look at, such as [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).  This is [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control) by Firefox 3.5 and later.

Comment: I also put a crossdomain.xml in the root directly, still doesn't read any text.

Comment: Crossdomain is for flash. No file you put anywhere will allow a javascript from another site to load from a script call.