# How to get Firebug to tell me what error jquery's .load() is returning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, load, firebug

I'm trying to find out what data/error jquery's .load() method is returning in the following code (the #content element is blank so I assume there is some kind of error).

1. **Where do I find in Firebug what content or error .load() is returning?**
2. **How can I use console.log to find out at least what content is being returned?**

[image]
<sub>(source: [deviantsart.com](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/ksqe5b.png))</sub>

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
            google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
                $('#loadButton').click(loadDataFromExernalWebsite);
            });
            function loadDataFromExernalWebsite() {
                console.log("test");
                $('#content').load('http://www.tanguay.info/web/getdata/index.php?url=http://www.tanguay.info/knowsite/data.txt', function() {
       alert('Load was performed.');
    });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <p>Click the button to load content:</p>
    <p id="content"></p>
    <input id="loadButton" type="button" value="load content"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your page in the *same domain* as the url you are trying to load?

Comment: yes, I uploaded it to http://www.tanguay.info/web/test/ajaxtest2.htm so it is in the same domain as the file it is loading, but it still doesn't show the text.

Comment: ok now it seems to be working online when on the same domain, seems to be key, just assumed that browsers had something in place to read crossdomain as well as do silverlight and flash

Comment: On a side note, you know jQuery 1.4.2 is the latest version, right?

Answer (score 3):

The **'Net'** tab of Firebug should show you all HTTP requests (including any from other domains)

Answer (score 1):

There is no error. Due to [SOO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (Same Origin Policy) for XMLHttpRequest, since you are requesting from a remote host (not the same domain as your application). XMLHttpRequest will just return nothing.

But if you modify your .load callback method signature to `function(response, status, xhr) {...}` the data returned will be in `response`. But in your case there will be nothing there.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to install [firequery](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/12632) and you can detect easily jquery problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#content").load("http://www.tanguay.info/web/getdata/index.php?url=http://www.tanguay.info/knowsite/data.txt", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    console.log("Error code :" + xhr.status); // error code
    console.log ("Error text :" + xhr.statusText); // error text
  }
});
```