# jQuery load() not working with http but does with local file

Tags: jquery

I have a simple function:

```
function goCV(what){ //'what' = htm filename 
  $('#cv_load_entry').load("http://<domain_name>/" + what);
}
```

The function works fine when the file is a local (with relative reference on my machine or in the same directory as the link-from file on the server).  But when I attempt to use an absolute reference (with `http://domain_name/filename.htm`), it does not work; and Firebug displays the GET in red (but doesn't tell me what the problem is that I can recognize from reading the Headers).

When I view the successful GET information in Firebug when executing the script from the server using relative referencing, it shows the full URL exactly as what is sent with the "http" part pre-pended to the filename variable.

I'm stumped.

PS: I'm using `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js`

UPDATE: I'm suspecting this is a cross-domain issue.  I'm going to try the proxy.php idea found on [Why doesn't jquery .load() load a text file from an external website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734676/why-doesnt-jquery-load-load-a-text-file-from-an-external-website?rq=1)

PROBLEM SOLVED: `http://christianheilmann.com/2010/01/10/loading-external-content-with-ajax-using-jquery-and-yql/`

Comment: is this a cross site request?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a cross-domain issue (you can test by changing the domain to the same one your webpage is on; the script should start working). If you control the remote server, or if it supports remote AJAX requests, you can use either [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) or [JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to access the data. Otherwise, you will need a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(goCV(what){
       jQuery("#cv_load_entry").load("http://<domain_name>/" + what);
   });
</script>
```