# POST json data using form

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I need to pass JSON data to a server. Data looks like this:

```
{"method":"like","data":{"type":1,"id":123}}
```

I need it to be done automaticaly, if I would use a form it can be done like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#form").submit();
});
</script>
```

But I need to pass data using $_POST in that exact format. How can this be done?

Comment: Pass it to a server from what?  JSON is just a string, you can just pass the string in a single post field.

Comment: Do you have user input from a form, or are you creating the data programmatically?

Comment: @tandu I need to pass a string like that to http://www.domain.com/script.php so I could know user has the page loaded. Also I need to do this automatically, can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

see jquery's [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) or better ([`post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) if you don't need to load anything to the page you're working on) to pass the json object with POST

If you don't know how to convert a string/array to json, use phps [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("script.php", { <?php echo $string; ?> },
       function() {
         alert("Your test.php page received the string!);
       });
});
```

That way the `$string` gets loaded automatically when the page is loaded (if user has javascript turned on).

Comment: Why `.load()`? The OP doesn't indicate that they want to load any of the server response into the DOM.

Comment: @nrabinowitz I need to pass a string like that to domain.com/script.php so I could know user has the page loaded. Also I need to do this automatically, can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: OK, got it so far, but why doesnt this work?
  `<script>$(document).ready(function(){
$.post("http://www.domain.com/app.php", {"method":"like","data":{"type":1,"id":233725822}},
   function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });
});
   </script>`
if there is just script.php it works, if i display other domain, then not

Comment: thats because jquery doesnt allow cross site scripting. there are a few workaround/hacks for this 'problem' though. for examples look [here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727183/can-jquery-ajax-call-external-webservice)

Comment: @danontheline can you give me an example how can I make a JSONP call? Just like the one you posted earlier just for another domain.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4505/discussion-between-treat-and-danontheline)