# Load external page elements into an array using jquery

Tags: arrays, jquery

How can I load a collection of page elements (EG. `<div class="myClass">`) from an external page into an array please?

Comment: Not enough details. See [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Sorry for not being totally clear with my question. I wish to load a collection of elements using jquery ajax into an array from an external page within the same domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very vague, but assuming you are using [`jQuery.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to fire an AJAX request to a remote page:

```
$.get("somePage.html", function(data) {
    var elems = $(data).filter(".myClass").get();
});
```

[`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) is used to reduce the elements of `data` to those matching the selector. [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns a normal array (rather than a jQuery object).

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I was messing up the syntax. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load elements from an external page in you script because that would be against the same origin policy. What you could do is using JSONP where I relate to this question: [can jquery ajax call external webservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727183/can-jquery-ajax-call-external-webservice)

Comment: Sorry. Yeah, this is not across domains. All the pages are hosted under the same domain.